# How user can change the tty information (related to CVE-2017-1000367)

Tags: vulnerability, incident-response, cve

Recently Red Hat fixed an important vulnerability in sudo:
https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-1000367

From the description:

> A flaw was found in the way sudo parsed tty information from the process status file in the proc filesystem. A local user with
>   privileges to execute commands via sudo could use this flaw to
>   escalate their privileges to root.

I wonder what the regular user should do to “use this flaw”?
Is it a simple operation?

Comment: Just search for this CVE in connection with the word "exploit" and you'll find https://github.com/c0d3z3r0/sudo-CVE-2017-1000367. Also http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/05/30/16 has a detailed description how this vulnerability can be used. If you consider this simple is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! This is great explanation http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/05/30/16